# JSF 2 portlet bridge + Apache Pluto

Tags: jsf-2, portlet

I use JSF 2.1 application as a portlet-module of Apache Pluto container. As a portlet bridge I use Jboss portlet bridge 3.2 Final . I delared it in my portlet.xml

`<portlet-class>javax.portlet.faces.GenericFacesPortlet</portlet-class>`

```
    <init-param>
        <name>javax.portlet.faces.defaultViewId.view</name>
        <value>/index.xhtml</value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <name>javax.portlet.faces.preserveActionParams</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <name>javax.portlet.faces.autoDispatchEvents</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </init-param>
```

When I run my application on server (is patched Tomee), first page (index.xhtml) looks correctly, but when I try to forward to another page by clicking on `<h:commandButton>`, the container cannot find needed page. Could you help me with this issue or advice another way to create portlet bridge?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the details of the `<h:commandButton>` code being used to trigger the next JSF page, as without that information it's very difficult to know what the problem might be?